# Exception understood on update Kinect Joint positions

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am doing a very simple stuff, my goal is to move one skeleton based on the position of the other skeleton, for this i am based myself on a HipCenter position.
(This algoritm could be wrong, this question is about a exception ocurring in the foreach loop)

Here is my actual code:

```
public static Skeleton MoveTo(this Skeleton skOrigin, Skeleton skDestiny)
{
     Skeleton skReturn = skOrigin; // just making a copy

        // find the factor to move, based on the HipCenter.
        float whatToMultiplyX = skOrigin.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.X / skDestiny.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.X;
        float whatToMultiplyY = skOrigin.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y / skDestiny.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y;
        float whatToMultiplyZ = skOrigin.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Z / skDestiny.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Z;


        SkeletonPoint movedPosition = new SkeletonPoint();
        Joint movedJoint = new Joint();
        foreach (JointType item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointType)))
        {
            // Updating the position
            movedPosition.X = skOrigin.Joints[item].Position.X * whatToMultiplyX;
            movedPosition.Y = skOrigin.Joints[item].Position.Y * whatToMultiplyY;
            movedPosition.Z = skOrigin.Joints[item].Position.Z * whatToMultiplyZ;

            // Setting the updated position to the skeleton that will be returned.
            movedJoint.Position = movedPosition;
            skReturn.Joints[item] = movedJoint;
        }

        return skReturn;
    }
```

Using F10 to debug everything works fine ultin the second pass in te foreach loop.
When i am passing for the second time in the foreach i get a exception on this line

```
skReturn.Joints[item] = movedJoint;
```

The exception says:

```
JointType index value must match Joint.JointType
```

But the value is actualy the Spine.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just referencing the `Joints` array by index?  I'll try to spin up my Kinect tomorrow and test the loop out to see if I can reproduce it too.

Comment: thanks man, but dont worry, i find a solution an will edit my question later. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi Ewerton, can you please publish your solution? I am having the same issue in a unit test that I would like to write...

Comment: @Ingo look, sorry for the late. Here is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved, here is the solution**

```
 Joint newJoint = new Joint(); // declare a new Joint

// Iterate in the 20 Joints
foreach (JointType item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointType)))
{
    newJoint = skToBeMoved.Joints[item];

            // applying the new values to the joint
            SkeletonPoint pos = new SkeletonPoint()
            {
                X = (float)(newJoint.Position.X + (someNumber)),
                Y = (float)(newJoint.Position.Y + (someNumber)),
                Z = (float)(newJoint.Position.Z + (someNumber))
            };

            newJoint.Position = pos;
            skToBeChanged.Joints[item] = newJoint;
        }
```

This will work.