# How to capture motion data in Kinect SDK V1.7 (Avateering XNA)?

Tags: c#-4.0, kinect, xna-4.0, kinect-sdk, motion-detection

I am new to the kinect sdk v1.7.

I want to know how to capture motion data from the sample .(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041.aspx)

so, how can I make a procedure that can capture the skeleton data into file ? (record)

then , read the file back to the sample program and model it.(play)?

my idea is record the skeleton data into file , then get the skeleton data from the file and let the Avatar play .

I can do what I want in another sample program . (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855381) , cause the sample program only draw the lines and skeleton points.

For example ,

```
00001 00:00:00.0110006@353,349,354,332,358,249,353,202,310,278,286,349,269,407,266,430,401,279,425,349,445,408,453,433,332,369,301,460,276,539,269,565,372,370,379,466,387,548,389,575,

00002 00:00:00.0150008@352,349,353,332,356,249,352,202,309,278,284,349,266,406,263,430,398,279,424,349,445,408,453,433,331,369,301,461,277,541,271,566,371,371,379,466,387,548,390,575,
```

[frame no.][timestamp]@[skeleton position coordinates]

in this example , i assume the skeleton position is the Joint Id order.

thanks (forgive my poor english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StreamWriter`, initialize it at the selected path, then for each frame, increase the frame counter, write it to the file, write the timestamp to the file, then loop through the joints and write them to the file. I would do this as follows:

```
using System.IO;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@path);
int frames = 0;

...

void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    frames++;
    using (SkeletonFrame sFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrameData())
    {
        if (sFrame == null)
            return;

        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

        Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons
                                where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                select s);
        if (skeleton == null)
            return;

        if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            writer.Write("{0} {1}@", frames, timestamp);//I dont know how you want to do this
            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                writer.Write(joint.Position.X + "," + joint.Position.Y + "," joint.Position.Z + ",");
            }
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to read from the file:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@path);
int frame = -1;
JointCollection joints;

...

string[] lines = reader.ReadAllLines();

...

void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Children.Clear();
    string[] coords = lines[frame].Split('@')[1].Split(',');
    int jointIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.Length; i += 3)
    {
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.Y = int.Parse(coords[i + 1]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i + 2]);
        jointIndex++;
    }

    DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.Spine, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Head }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    depthFrame.Dispose();

    frame++;
}

Point GetDisplayPosition(Joint joint, DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Canvas skeleton)
{
    float depthX, depthY;
    KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
    DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat = sensor.DepthStream.Format;
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

    depthX = depthPoint.X;
    depthY = depthPoint.Y;

    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

    int colorX, colorY;
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(depthImageFormat, depthPoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
    colorX = colorPoint.X;
    colorY = colorPoint.Y;

    return new System.Windows.Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
}

Polyline GetBodySegment(Joint[] joints, Brush brush, JointType[] ids, DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Canvas canvas)
{
    PointCollection points = new PointCollection(ids.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; ++i)
    {
        points.Add(GetDisplayPosition(joints[i], depthFrame, canvas));
    }
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
    polyline.Points = points;
    polyline.Stroke = brush;
    polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
    return polyline;
}
```

Of course, this only works in wpf. You will just need to change from using the code:

```
    DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.Spine, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Head }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    depthFrame.Dispose();
```

To how the avateering sample animates the model, you could even create a new `Skeleton` and copy `joints` to `Skeleton.Joints`, then just pass that skeleton as the "detected" skeleton. Note you would need to change any other needed variables that are required for functions used in this sample. I am unfamiliar with the sample so I can't give specific method names, but you can just replace the global `Skeleton` with the one you created at the beginning and update every frame. So I would recommend this:

```
//in the game class (AvateeringXNA.cs)
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@path);
int frame = -1;
JointCollection joints;
Skeleton recorded = new Skeleton();

...

string[] lines = reader.ReadAllLines();

...

void Update(...)
{
    string[] coords = lines[frame].Split('@')[1].Split(',');
    int jointIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.Length; i += 3)
    {
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.Y = int.Parse(coords[i + 1]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i + 2]);
        jointIndex++;
    }

    recorded.Joints = joints;

    ...

    //preform necessary methods, except with recorded skeleton instead of detected, I think it is:
    this.animator.CopySkeleton(recorded);
    this.animator.FloorClipPlane = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane;

    // Reset the filters if the skeleton was not seen before now
    if (this.skeletonDetected == false)
    {
        this.animator.Reset();
    }

    this.skeletonDetected = true;
    this.animator.SkeletonVisible = true;

    ...

    frame++;
}
```

**EDIT**

When you read the initial floor clip plane (`clipPlanes[0]`) it will get the entire frame information up to the first space. See below to see how it will split and how I would read it:

```
var newFloorClipPlane = Tuple.Create(Single.Parse(clipPlanes[2]), Single.Parse(clipPlanes[3]), Single.Parse(clipPlanes[4]), Single.Parse(clipPlanes[5]));
```

Here is how you lay out the frames:

```
frame# timestam@joint1Posx,joint1posy,joint1posz,...jointNPosx,jointNposy,jointNposz floorX floorY floorZ floorW
```

Here is the array produced by `.Split(' ')

```
["frame#", "timestam@joint1Posx,joint1posy,joint1posz,...jointNPosx,jointNposy,jointNposz", "floorX", "floorY", "floorZ", "floorW"]
```

Therefore, with an example input of:

```
00000002 10112@10,10,10... 11 12 13 14
```

With your code you will get:

```
[2, 10112101010..., 11, 12]
```

With corrected indexes from my code:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Put this line of into a console application really fast and see what it outputs:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToSingle("10,10"));
```

The output is `1010` For what you are trying to accomplish, this creates the wrong floor clip plane. You need the proper indexes for what you are trying to achieve.

note: I changed `Convert.ToSingle` to `Single.Parse` because it is better practice and in the stack trace they both preform the same functions

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
But I want to do this with the sample program(Avatarring)
I can't find any the frames information in the sample program.
and I want to record the skeleton information and put it back to the avatar , and play.
But I only can find the information about skeleton is skeleton[] object . How can I record the object in a txt(string) format . and turn back to avatar model ?

Comment: I mean that I want to modify the sample program that can capture motion data. But I do not know how to do this .

Comment: You can use my same code to capture the motion, as it saves the joint coordinates, and you would read it the same way, you just then instead of writing to a canvas convert it to world points and set the avatar's joints to it relatively... Ill make edits really fast @user255

Comment: I got some trouble when I was doing this step 【recorded.Joints = joints;】 ，the error message show that 【The property or indexer 'Microsoft.Kinect.Skeleton.Joints' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible】，How can I solve it?

Comment: @user2553644 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556910/how-to-make-a-copy-of-an-kinect-skeleton-object-to-another-kinect-skeleton-objec

Comment: I have read the article , but I still do not understand how to set the jointCollection property into the joints of the new skeleton object . In this article , I can not find any place to set my recorded jointCollection .

Comment: I think that I can set the joint in this loop【for (int i = 0; i < coords.Length; i += 3)】，like this【recorded.Joints[(JointType)jointIndex] = newdJoint;】，is the method can do the same thing the original code does?

Comment: another question is that in this step【this.animator.FloorClipPlane = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane;】how can I create a new skeletonFrame.FloorClopPlane to let me put into the avatar?

Comment: @user2553644 The loop should work, and the original methods should continue to function properly, and just store an older clip plane as the new one

Comment: I try the code 【recorded.Joints[(JointType)jointIndex] = newdJoint;】，but I get error 【JointType index value must match Joint.JointType】，I search for solution ,then I saw this article . But I still can't solve it . I have no idea where the code he change,and I still don't know that the problem is.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544978/exception-understood-on-update-kinect-joint-positions/13594350#13594350

Comment: @user2553644 That means you must pass the index as type JointType, where you are passing an int, try `recorded.Joints[newdjoint.Item] = newdjoint;`

Comment: thanks for your help , but how can I store an older clip plane? use binary streamWriter? , is there exist a way to new a SkeletonFrame (the system message show that it doesn't exist constructor)?

Comment: @user2553644 You could write the x y z w coordinates of the floorclipplane to the end of each frame and add a similar method for handling it. Then update it before you update the skeleton

Comment: Thanks for your help , I have already finished the "record" , but I still can not play the avatar . I don't know why. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/r9JxB8L0 [base on your code] , the avatar is not move ,and do nothing [http://tinyurl.com/kadjwdy
].

Comment: Is there need to change anything in draw()?

Comment: @user2553644 Hmmm... Can I see the code where you write the floorclipplane?

Comment: here is my all code [AvateeringXNA.cs] -->http://pastebin.com/kMD2Nz2p .  I write the 4 items of the floorclipplane into a file. and read it back .

Comment: I don't understand that your edits. why the clipPlanes[0] is wrong ? I  recorded it at the same time .[joints : clipplanes] and the clipplanes are the 4 items [item1~4] . when I read it back from recorded file. why is  clipPlanes[0] ? and in your edits ...where is the clipplane[1]???? why 2~5?

Comment: @user2553644 The reason I have made those edits is because you have spaces in your data file before the actual floor clip planes. If you read my edit entirely I explain this, as the single will be improperly converted then

Comment: I already found the problem is . Thanks for your help . I have done the replay . I used the clipPlane 4 initial item to 0 . And I use the serialize and deserialize to record/replay skeleton object to/from file .The problem is that the avatar need not only skeleton joint information but also need other skeleton object property. I really appreciate your help . But I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer..sorry.

Comment: @SiriusWang Great! Just for my own curiosity on this subject what else did you need to write? Also you can accept my answer or add a new one and accept it

Comment: I accepted it. I write the whole skeleton object to file by using serialize and read it back by using deserialize . It may loss something the avatar needed that I don't know . I gave the avatar whole information , then solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you use the csv method to write all the joints data in terms of excel file. It would help you to analyse them at a later stage. I have customized my code for putting them in csv format which helped me to analyse at later stage of data. You can write a separate file in your project which would export all the skeleton data

```
public void CoordinatesExportToCSV(Skeleton data)
    {
        if (!TimeRecorded)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeRecorded = true;
        }
        recordedSamples[1]++;
        if (!titles)
        {
            sw1.Write("Counter,Time,Clipped Edges,");
            foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
            {
                sw1.Write(joint.JointType.ToString()+",");
            }
            titles = true;
        }
        else
        {
            double a = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds - startTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
            sw1.Write(recordedSamples[1] + "," + a + "," + data.ClippedEdges);

            foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
            {
                sw1.Write(joint.Position.X + "|" + joint.Position.Y + "|" + joint.Position.Z+",");
            }
        }
        sw1.WriteLine();
    }
```